# Eigenvalue ratio evolution of Laplacian matrix when add edges

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Consider an connected digraph, we use the classic definition of the Laplacian matrix $L$:

$L=D-A$, where $D$ is the degree matrix and $A$ is the adjacency matrix.

There has been many researches on how the eigenvalue will evolve when adding edges to the graph, (such as [Bojan Mohar](http://www.fmf.uni-lj.si/~mohar/Papers/Spec.pdf), the interlace of the eigenvalues, etc.).

But I am wondering if there is some work focus on the eigenvalue ratio of the Laplacian matrix, for instance, $\frac{\lambda_i}{\lambda_2}$, where $0=\lambda_1<\lambda_2\leq\cdots\leq\lambda_N$ are the eigenvalues of the Laplacian.